# Can't get rid of modulenotfounderrror after moving project dirs around

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-django-storages

when I run python manage.py runserver on myenv, I get the "modulenotfounderror" "no module named Quicpull" - which is my project Dir.

I've tried multiple syntaxes in my installed apps, and I've updated the system env paths.